# Tensorflow reusing variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a pixel-wise classification LSTM RNN using tensorflow. My model is displayed in the picture below. The problem I'm having is building a 3D LSTM RNN. The code that I have builds a 2D LSTM RNN, so I placed the code inside a loop, but now I get the following error:

`ValueError: Variable RNN/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Matrix does not exist, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?`

So here's the network:

[image]

The idea goes like this... an input image of size (200,200) is the input into a LSTM RNN of size (200,200,200). Each sequence output from the LSTM tensor vector (the pink boxes in the LSTM RNN) is fed into a MLP, and then the MLP makes a single output prediction -- ergo pixel-wise prediction (you can see how one input pixel generates one output "pixel"

So here's my code:

```
...
n_input_x = 200
n_input_y = 200

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input_x, n_input_y])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input_x, n_input_y])

def RNN(x):
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input_x])
    x = tf.split(0, n_steps, x)

    output_matrix = []
    for i in xrange(200):
        temp_vector = []
        lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
        outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
        for j in xrange(200):
            lstm_vector = outputs[j]
            pixel_pred = multilayer_perceptron(lstm_vector, mlp_weights, mlp_biases)
            temp_vector.append(pixel_pred)
        output_matrix.append(temp_vector)
        print i

    return output_matrix

temp = RNN(x)
pred = tf.placeholder(temp, [None, n_input_x, n_input_y])
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
...
```

You can see that I placed the call to `RNN` inside the first loop. In this way, I generate a new RNN every time. I know Tensorflow auto-increments other Tensors.

debugging I have

```
(Pdb) lstm_cell
<tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell object at 0x7f9d26956850>
```

and then for outputs I have a vector of 200 BasicLSTMCells

```
(Pdb) len(outputs)
200
...
<tf.Tensor 'RNN_2/BasicLSTMCell_199/mul_2:0' shape=(?, 200) dtype=float32>]
```

So ideally, I want the second call to RNN to generate LSTM tensors with indexes 200-399

I tried this, but it won't construct a RNN because the dimensions of 40000 and x (after the split) don't line up.

```
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input_x])
# Split to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_hidden)
# This input shape is required by `rnn` function
x = tf.split(0, n_input_y, x)
lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(40000, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
output_matrix = []
for i in xrange(200):
    temp_vector = []
    for j in xrange(200):
        lstm_vector = outputs[i*j]
```

So then I also tried to get rid of the split, but then it complains that it must be a list. So then I tried reshaping `x = tf.reshape(x, [n_input_x * n_input_y])` but then it still says `it must be a list`

Comment: Didn't read your code, but using RNN on pixels seems bad. I would advise you to use convolutions and deconvolutions to have a pixel-wise prediction map (see [this paper](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf))

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot I've actually read that paper, and I am going to try that in the future, but I want to try and make this work first

Comment: Here your LSTM is iterating on the columns of the image? You can also give [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06759) a try if you like RNNs

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot cool, I missed that paper